# Salvar dados numa Activity ao mudar de Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

O programa é um contador, ao clicar no botão + ele adiciona +1 a variavel cont1...cont2..., Quero que quando eu clique no relatorio e eu voltar a esta pagina, os dados que eu adicionei a variavel estarem la. Sempre quando eu clico no relatorio e volto a esta pagina, reseta todos os dados. Dei uma pesquisada e devo usar o SaveInstanceState, gostaria de saber como aplicar ao meu código.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button add, dim;
private TextView opt3010, opt3020, opt360, opt380, opt390, opt780, vst3268, vst3250, mon, vay;
private int cont1, cont2, cont3, cont4, cont5, cont6, cont7, cont8, cont9, cont10 = 0;
private int totalMaq = 0;




private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.navigation_telarelatorio:
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TelaRelatorio.class);
                startActivity(intent1);
                break;
            case R.id.navigation_telavazia:
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TelaVazia.class);
                startActivity(intent2);
               break;
        }
        return false;
    }
};



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
    Menu menu = navigation.getMenu();
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.getItem(0);
    menuItem.setChecked(true);

    opt3010 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.opt3010);
    opt3020 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.opt3020);
    opt360 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.opt360);
    opt380 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.opt380);
    opt390 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.opt390);
    opt780 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.opt780);
    vst3250 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.vst3250);
    vst3268 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.vst3268);
    mon = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mon);
    vay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.vay);


    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            cont1++;

            opt3010.setText("" + cont1);
            totalMaq++;
        }
    });
```

TelaRelatorio

```
public class TelaRelatorio extends AppCompatActivity {

private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:
                Intent intent3 = new Intent(TelaRelatorio.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent3);
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

@SuppressLint("ResourceType")
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.telarelatorio);

    BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

    Menu menu = navigation.getMenu();
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.getItem(1);
    menuItem.setChecked(true);
}
```

}

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Como a própria documentação oficial diz, a Activity é destruída e recriada cada vez que o usuário gira a tela. Veja aqui: [Como recriar uma atividade](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating?hl=pt-br)

Utilizando o **onSaveInstanceState** podemos salvar o estado da Activity toda vez que o usuário girar a tela e recuperar com o **onRestoreInstanceState**

**onSaveInstanceState**

```
static final String STATE_SCORE = "playerScore";
static final String STATE_LEVEL = "playerLevel";

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Save the user's current game state
savedInstanceState.putInt(STATE_SCORE, mCurrentScore);
savedInstanceState.putInt(STATE_LEVEL, mCurrentLevel);

// Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

**onRestoreInstanceState**

```
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Always call the superclass so it can restore the view hierarchy
super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

// Restore state members from saved instance
mCurrentScore = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SCORE);
mCurrentLevel = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_LEVEL);
}
```

Espero ter ajudado.
Se alguém conseguir fazer de outro jeito, por favor, nos ensine. ;)

Abraço.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que utilizar SharePreference é muito mais fácil. Crie uma classe e mande salvar todos os dados sempre que sair, ou seja, salve no método `onPause`, pesquise sobre, mas se precisar de mais detalhes me avise.